# Urllib2 Python Error

Tags: python, mysql, urllib2

I Have Been Writing A Robots.txt Downloader Of A List Of Website Using Python and Urllib2 . The Following is the code

```
    import MySQLdb
    import urllib
    import urllib2
    clone=0
    db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","research" )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM sites"
    try:
     cursor.execute(sql)
         # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
     results = cursor.fetchall()
     for row in results:
     id = row[0]
     website = row[1]
     website=website+"robots.txt"
     print website
     try:
        check = urllib2.urlopen(website,timeout=10).code
        if not check: 
            print "No WEBSERVER FOUND"
            clone=1
     except IOError:
        clone=1
        print "No Webserver Found"
     if(check==200 or clone==0):
        sql2 = "UPDATE sites SET robots_txt_available=1 WHERE ID=%s" % \
            (id)
                    cursor.execute(sql)
        print website," Has Robots.txt.";
    else:print website," does not Have robots.txt."
    except:
            print "Error: unable to fecth data"

            # disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

The Output of the code is :

```
 http://rashtrapatisachivalaya.gov.in/robots.txt
 No Webserver Found
 Error: unable to fecth data
```

So it is Not Completely Executing . Can Anyone Please Tell What is the Problem in this Code.

Comment: Somehow, I was expecting MixedCase variable names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your point? The given URL just does not exist and for that reason the code in the except clause is being executed. And the 'code' attribute access is only executed when there is no exception...

The proper solution is

```
import urllib2
try:
   urllib2.urlopen("some url")
except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
   if err.code == 404:
       <whatever>
   else:
       raise
```

Comment: Yes Thats What I Am Trying To Well. If One Website Doesnt Occur then The Rest Of the Code Doesnt Execute(i.e Rest OF Websites).

Comment: Please what? Ask a coherent question ...